# Proof for continuous function on a discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

> Proposition:
>
> Let X and Y be non-empty sets and let $\tau$ and $\nu$ be, respectively, the discrete topologies on X and Y.
> Every function
> $f: \left ( X,\tau \right )\rightarrow \left ( Y,\nu \right )$ is continuous.

Here's my attempt at the proof:

> Recall that for any two topological space $\left ( X,\tau \right )$ and $\left ( Y,\nu \right )$, a function
> $f:\left ( X,\tau \right )\rightarrow \left ( Y,\nu \right )$ is called continuous IFF for every $u \in \nu$, we have $f^{-1}\left ( u \right )\in \tau$

Now,
$\tau$ is discrete on X so $\tau=\left \{ \varnothing,\left \{ u_{i} \right \}_{i \in I} \right \}$ where $X \in \left \{ u_{i} \right \}_{i \in I}$

Also, $\nu$ is discrete topology on Y so $\nu=\left \{ \varnothing,\left \{ u_{i} \right \}_{i \in I} \right \}$ where $Y \in \left \{ u_{i} \right \}_{i \in I}$

Indeed, $f^{-1}\left ( \varnothing \right )=\varnothing \in Y$.
Then, $f^{-1}\left ( u \right )=\left \{ x \in X \mid f\left ( x \right ) \in Y \right \}=X$ since the map f is between the topological space $\left ( X,\tau \right ) to \left ( Y,\nu \right ).$

Obviously, $\left \{ u_{i} \right \}_{i \in I}\setminus Y$ are subsets of Y smaller than Y itself.
Since every element $u \in Y$ is mapped from X, then clearly, every element in $\left \{ u_{i} \right \}_{i \in I}\setminus Y$ are from X too.
Hence, $f^{-1}\left ( \left \{ u_{i} \right \}_{i \in I}\setminus Y \right ) \in X \in \tau$.

Hence, f is continuous.

Is my proof flawed?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with $\{u_i\}_{i\in I}$? I should say $\tau=\wp(X)$.

Comment: I meant that to be the collection of subsets of Y in $\nu$ without the empty set being included-included in $\nu$ but separately.@drhab

Comment: What's the use of setting them apart from $\varnothing$ which is also a subset of $X$ in $\tau$? Do you agree with $\tau=\wp(X)$ (i.e. $\tau$ is the collection of all subsets of $X$)? No bothering with indices and immediately clear.

Comment: Yes I agree. I understand that in general, there is no need for separation of the empty set but it was done so to reduce confusion. I don't in particular enjoy indexing notations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The discrete topology on $X$ is *not*  $\tau=\{\varnothing,\{u_i\}_{i∈I}\}$. While each $\{u_i\}_{i∈I}$ is indeed open, this in fact implies every subset of $X$ is open (because a union of open sets is open), so $\tau = \mathcal{P}(X)$ (the power set of $X$).

Since every subset of $X$ is open, the preimage of every set in $Y$ is open. You don't even need to assume $Y$ has the discrete topology.

Answer (score 2):

I think you make things more complicated than necessary.

If $X$ is equipped with discrete topology then *every* function $f:X\to Z$ (where $Z$ denotes an arbitrary topological space) is continuous.

This because the preimage of *every* subset of $Z$ w.r.t. $f$ is an open set.

Note that these preimages are subsets of $X$ and *every* subset of $X$ is open. This because $X$ is equipped with the discrete topology: $\tau_X=\wp(X)$.

The looks of the topology on $Z$ is completely irrelevant.